# How to change a cell value periodically in libreoffice calc?

Tags: macros, libreoffice-calc

The title says it all...

For example, if I want to have a cell which displays the current time and auto updates minute by minute (well, I think we call that a clock), how do I do it?

Is there a simple function implemented already or should I create a macro and assign it to a specific event?

**EDIT:** Following the provided answer by @Jim K, I want to be more clear about what I want. The "clock" example above was here to make it simple to understand, but what I really want is in the title: **a cell value which changes periodically, be it a string, a number, a date...**

Comment: Well, if it is possible, yes! As a whole recalculation would update dates and times if cells value are "=NOW()", and that I don"t want. These cells should remain what they were set to, ideally.

Comment: Exactly. I would like to change a specific cell value (be it a number, a string or whatever value it has) in time without intefering with the rest of the document. Do you have something in mind?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First enter `=NOW()` in a cell, and format the number by going to Format -> Cells.

Next, this Basic macro (from [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=44&t=59369)) recalculates every minute.  Go to Tools -> Customize and assign it to the `Open Document` event.

```vb
Sub RecalculatePeriodically
   Const secs = 60
   On Error Goto ErrorHandler
   Do While True
      Wait(1000 * secs)
      ThisComponent.calculateAll()
   Loop
   ErrorHandler:
       'Document was probably closed
End Sub
```

However, this crashes when exiting LibreOffice.  So instead, use the following threaded Python macro (like [here](https://forum.openoffice.org/en/forum/viewtopic.php?f=45&t=72581)).  Assign `keep_recalculating_thread` to the `Open Document` event.

```py
import time
from threading import Thread
import uno

def keep_recalculating_thread(action_event=None):
    t = Thread(target = keep_recalculating)
    t.start()

def keep_recalculating():
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    while hasattr(oDoc, 'calculateAll'):
        oDoc.calculateAll()
        time.sleep(60)

g_exportedScripts = keep_recalculating_thread,
```

Another idea is at https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/5327/how-can-i-run-a-macro-at-regular-time-interval/, although it requires linking to another file which seems cumbersome.

**EDIT**:

Maybe you are looking for something like this?  Test it by starting with a blank spreadsheet and entering `1` in cell A1.

```py
def keep_changing_cell(action_event=None):
    t = Thread(target = keep_changing_thread)
    t.start()

def keep_changing_thread():
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oSheet = oDoc.CurrentController.ActiveSheet
    COLUMN_A = 0
    FIRST_ROW = 0
    oCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(COLUMN_A, FIRST_ROW)
    while hasattr(oDoc, 'calculateAll'):
        oCell.setValue(oCell.getValue() + 1)
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution. But I took the "clock" example to make it simple to understand what it should do, but with your code it updates ALL the cells and if inside there is a "=NOW()" formula, the cell value changes... So I cannot have more than 1 cell with that formula indide! What I was looking for was a way to change a specific cell value periodically. Updating my OP.

Comment: I'm trying to make your edited version to work, but I never used python before and I cannot figure how to include the script in my calc document, despite the fact I followed this [tutorial](http://christopher5106.github.io/office/2015/12/06/openoffice-libreoffice-automate-your-office-tasks-with-python-macros.html). There is no script embeded with my document. Any help with that as well?

Comment: Let's talk about this in a [chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148785/room-for-jim-k-and-slander).

Comment: Problem solved (didn't have python correctly installed for LibreOffice)! Thanks @Jim K

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

> Is there a simple function implemented already

No.

From [LibreOffice](https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/86706/how-to-set-the-font-clock-and-alignment/) and fairly recent:

> (I don't know a 'clock' property applying to cells.)

There are simple ways to obtain the time, for example given suitable formatting, with date:

```
=NOW()
```

or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>;</kbd>

Or, for example, without date:

```
=MOD(NOW(),1)
```

The first and last will update, but only when the sheet is recalculated.

For a cell that ticks away (eg second by second) I believe you will need a script.