# This cell duplicates image in that cell in spreadsheet?

Tags: openoffice-calc

Very simple.  Cell A1 has an image in it, which I supply through Insert:Picture:From File...

Now I want Cell A3 to automatically show the same picture.  I simply can't find a way-- certainly the "=" doesn't work.  At this point, I don't care if the images are "links" or embedded, I just want it to work.  Can it?  Thx.

**Edit, 09-01-17**, based on Jim K's idea, here's macro code I have installed:

```vb
REM  *****  BASIC  *****

Private oListener   as Object
Private cellA1      as Object

Sub AddListener

    Dim Doc, Sheet, Cell as Object

    Doc         = ThisComponent
    Sheet       = Doc.Sheets.getByName("Sheet1")
    cellA1      = Sheet.getCellrangeByName("A1")

    'create a listener
    oListener   = createUnoListener("Modify_","com.sun.star.util.XModifyListener")

    'register the listener
    cellA1.addModifyListener(oListener)

End Sub

Sub Modify_disposing(oEv)
End Sub

Sub RmvListener
    cellA1.removeModifyListener(oListener)
End Sub

' macro jumps here when oListener detects modification of Sheet

Sub Modify_modified(oEv)

    Doc             = ThisComponent
    Sheet           = Doc.Sheets.getByIndex(0)
    originCell      = Sheet.getCellByPosition(0,0)
    originValue     = originCell.Value

    if originValue then
        print "originValue is " & originValue
    else
        print "originValue zero"
    end if

End Sub
```

The problem, ironically, is that it *works*.  It works for integers and {non-value}, I mean an empty cell.

So any integer not zero prints TRUE, zero prints FALSE, and empty cell prints FALSE.

But that's where it quits working-- any kind of string "asdf" also returns FALSE.

Maybe that could be fixed, but there's something a lot worse:  When I paste an image in the cell, or use the Insert/Image/From File... menu, or Cut an existing image...  Nothing happens! The Sheet Modified business does not trigger the expected routine.

Any hope?  Thx.

Comment: One way is to write a macro that copies and pastes the image.  It can be set up to run on the "Content changed" sheet event.  If you want to try this approach and get stuck, edit the question to post code you have so far, and state the problems encountered.

Comment: Ok, thx, I'll try that and get back.

Comment: Main post updated... (I don't think that sets off any triggers?)

Comment: The way that seems to work best is to edit the post and also add a short comment so that people know it has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

As you discovered, the solution in my comment does not work, because the `Content changed` event will not trigger when images are added.  I looked into other events as well, but they did not work either.

So instead, we can set up a function that runs periodically.  Each time it runs, it checks the count of images, and if any have been added or removed, it calls `update_copied_images()` below, which currently simply reports the value of cell A1, as in your code.

As explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44988206/5100564), I have not gotten a timer loop to work in Basic without crashing, so we can use [Python](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Python_as_a_macro_language) instead (a better language, so this is not a drawback in my opinion).

```py
import time
from threading import Thread
import uno

COLUMN_A, COLUMN_B, COLUMN_C = 0, 1, 2
FIRST_ROW = 0

def start_counting_images(action_event=None):
    t = Thread(target = keep_counting_images)
    t.start()

def keep_counting_images():
    oDoc = XSCRIPTCONTEXT.getDocument()
    oSheet = oDoc.getSheets().getByIndex(0)
    oDrawPage = oSheet.getDrawPage()
    messageCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(COLUMN_C, FIRST_ROW)
    messageCell.setString("Starting...")
    prevCount = -1
    while hasattr(oDoc, 'calculateAll'):  # keep going until document is closed
        count = oDrawPage.Count
        if prevCount == -1 or prevCount != count:
            prevCount = count
            messageCell.setString("Number of Images: " + str(prevCount))
            update_copied_images(oSheet)
        time.sleep(1)

def update_copied_images(oSheet):
    originCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(COLUMN_A, FIRST_ROW)
    originString = originCell.getString()
    messageCell = oSheet.getCellByPosition(COLUMN_B, FIRST_ROW)
    if len(originString):
        messageCell.setString("originString '" + originString + "'")
    else:
        messageCell.setString("originString length is zero")

g_exportedScripts = start_counting_images,
```

To run, go to Tools -> Macros -> Run Macro, find the .py file under My Macros where you put this code, and run `start_counting_images`.